# Capturing minimal substring without matching preceeding extra matching lookbehinds

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a phrase within two known strings. However if there are multiple lookbehinds, these appear in the capture group even with a lazy quantifier. For example:

Using this regex in python:

`(?<=Lookbehind:)(.*?)(?= Lookahead)`

Will match the bolded substrings below, when I just want to match "Text to Capture".

Lookbehind: **Test Lookbehind: Text to Capture** Lookahead
Lookbehind: **Lookbehind: Text to Capture** Lookahead
Lookbehind: **Text to Capture** Lookahead

What would be a better query to capture the "Text to Capture" wildcard group while matching as little as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to insert a negative *lookahead* after the first positive lookbehind which asserts that the `Lookbehind` is the final one:

```regex
(?<=Lookbehind: )(?!.*Lookbehind: )(.*?)(?= Lookahead)
```

### Demo

Explanation:

```regex
(?<=Lookbehind: )   assert that what precedes is "Lookbehind: "
(?!.*Lookbehind: )  but also assert that we CAN'T find another "Lookbehind: "
                    later in the input
(.*?)               text to capture
(?= Lookahead)      assert that what follows is " Lookahead"
```